# Python: Issue with animation from 3D matrix

Tags: arrays, animation, 3d

I´ve tried run following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
from matplotlib import cm #color map

u = np.array([[[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]],[[0,0,0],[0,2,0],[0,0,0]],[[0,0,0],[0,3,0],[0,0,0]]])
x = [-1,0,1]
y = [-1,0,1]
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = axes3d.Axes3D(fig)

def update(i, ax, fig):
    ax.cla()
    wframe = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, u[:,:,i],rstride=1,cstride=1,cmap=cm.coolwarm)
    ax.set_zlim3d(-1,1)
    print("step= ",i)
    return wframe

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,update,frames=3,fargs=(ax, fig),interval=1000)
ani.save('ani.mp4',bitrate=-1,codec="libx264")
```

The animation is, however, not functioning properly - it takes 2 times the prime step (i=0) and then, it is looping over a over again. Can you please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Added `init` function and `repeat=False`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
from matplotlib import cm #color map

u = np.array([[[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]],[[0,0,0],[0,2,0],[0,0,0]],[[0,0,0],[0,3,0],[0,0,0]]])
x = [-1,0,1]
y = [-1,0,1]
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = axes3d.Axes3D(fig)

def init():
    wframe = ax.plot_surface([], [], [], rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
    return wframe

def update(i, ax, fig):
    ax.cla()
    wframe = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, u[:,:,i],rstride=1,cstride=1,cmap=cm.coolwarm)
    ax.set_zlim3d(-1,1)
    print("step= ",i)
    return wframe

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,update,init_func=init, frames=3,fargs=(ax, fig),interval=1000,repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!